# Can I develop mac/iphone/ipad applications without having to paying first?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I'm interested to know if I can have access to all the libraries, ide, etc for the iphone/ipad/macos without paying the 90 bucks(for learning purpose).

Do I have to pay to have access to everything in order to start developing? I'm not talking about the istore by the way. I know that there is a fee for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Easy peasy! :) (not programming related, though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download the SDK and simulator for free.  If you want to install it on a iPhone, iPod Touch or iPad for testing, or submit to the store, you have to pay the $99.
http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/develop.html#compare

The simulator is useful for some testing, but it has many limitations. If you're developing applications that use the camera or other hardware devices, certain types of multi-touch, etc you're going to want to try it on a real device sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 2):

Developing for the Mac is, on the other hand, completely free.

Comment: Update: you now have to pay a nominal fee for XCode 4.0.

Comment: Update, now it seems you don't anymore if you have a free developer account!

Answer (score 1):

You can start developing iPhone/iPad apps for free but you must pay in order to test your applications on real devices. Without paying you can just test your applications in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iPhone Simulator for free, but to install on your device you'll need to join the developer program in order to create the certificates needed to install apps on a real device, even if it's just yours. This assumes that you don't have a jailbroken device.